# SDL2 Window is not being created

Tags: c, sdl

What happens when THIS fails to open a window. The program run, I can see it in my dock, but no window appears. This is pretty much the bare minimum needed to open a window using the SDL li

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    SDL_Window      *window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface     *surface = NULL;
    int windowFlags;

    windowFlags = 0;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("practice", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 900, 900, windowFlags);

    if (!window)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %d x %d window: %s\n", WIN_L, WIN_H, SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(6000);
    return (0);
}
```

I've tried to narrow it down to it's barest of bones to find the issue, and what you see is that process.

Comment: You ***need*** an event loop for the program to handle all events from the OS. Like actually showing the window.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I couldn't find that in the tutorial. I must be looking at an outdated tutorial. That's EXACTLY what the problem was, I appreciate it.